# ASP.NET MVC passing Model *together* with files back to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, httppostedfile, httppostedfilebase

Ok, I've been going at this for several hours and I simply cannot find the solution.

I want to get some data from my user. So first, I use a controller to create a view which receives a Model:

```
public ViewResult CreateArticle()
{
    Article newArticle = new Article();
    ImagesUploadModel dataFromUser = new ImagesUploadModel(newArticle);
    return View(dataFromUser);
}
```

Then, I have the view:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">

    <h2>AddArticle</h2>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("CreateArticle", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){ %>


                <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.newArticle.Title)%>
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newArticle.Title)%>

                <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.newArticle.ContentText)%>
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newArticle.ContentText)%>

                <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.newArticle.CategoryID)%>
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newArticle.CategoryID)%>

                <p>
                    Image1: <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    Image2: <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" />
                </p>

            <div>
                <button type="submit" />Create
            </div>



    <%} %>


</asp:Content>
```

and finally - the original controller, but this time configured to accept the data:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateArticle(ImagesUploadModel dataFromUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase[] imagesArr;
            imagesArr = new HttpPostedFileBase[2]; 
            int i = 0;
            foreach (string f in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[f];
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                    imagesArr[i] = file;
            }
```

The rest of this controller does not matter since no matter what I do, the `count` attribute of `Request.Files` (or `Request.Files.Keys`) remains 0. I simply can't find a way to pass the files from the form (the Model passes just fine).

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC posted file model binding when parameter is Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960687/asp-net-mvc-posted-file-model-binding-when-parameter-is-model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider not posting the files with the rest of the form- there are [good reasons and other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851318/asp-net-mvc-1-to-many-saving-post-and-upload-files/851326#851326) you can achieve what you want.

Also, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653469/how-can-i-upload-a-file-and-save-it-to-a-stream-for-further-preview-using-c/1653508#1653508) and [this advice](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx) regarding file uploads in MVC.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll just split it up into 2 views then :-P

thanks.

Comment: It could even be the same view with two forms in it (another way to achieve the "2 step process").

Answer (score 3):

You could add the files to your view model:

```
public class ImagesUploadModel
{
    ...
    public HttpPostedFileBase File1 { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File2 { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateArticle(ImagesUploadModel dataFromUser)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Use dataFromUser.File1 and dataFromUser.File2 directly here
    }
    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

Comment: that would be an awesome solution, but how do I update the model data in the view. that is - how does the upload mechanism work (what replaces <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" /> ?)

Comment: There's no HTML helper built into ASP.NET MVC currently that allows you to generate file inputs. You need to generate them manually or use one of the helpers in MVCContrib.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll just split it up into 2 views then :-P

thanks.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Got error:- No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'CommentModel' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'

Comment: @ujjaval, you seem to be attempting to use this in a Web API controller action. My answer is about ASP.NET MVC.